# Worksheets("Worksheet 1").Activate doesn't always work :-(

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel macro which resets which worksheet is active before closing the file. If I go straight to save i.e. by performing ctrl-S, activate works. If I try to save before closing, activate does NOT work. In the code below, if I do a straight ctrl-S then Workbook_BeforeSave() is run
(Activate method works). If I try to close the document, Workbook_BeforeClose() is run and I then choose "Yes" when asked "Would you like to save before closing?" which calls Workbook_Before Save() (Activate does NOT work).

Why does Activate not work when Workbook_BeforeSave() is called via Workbook_BeforeClose()?

Thanks, Helen.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim TempUserWantsToSaveFile As Integer

Cancel = False
 If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
     'Workbook has changed since last save.
     'Does user have permission to save the document?
     ' Only prompt to save if the user is David, Rob or myself.
     If (Environ("UserName") <> "dwilson") And _
        (Environ("UserName") <> "DWilson") And _
        (Environ("UserName") <> "RGrant") And _
        (Environ("UserName") <> "rgrant") And _
        (Environ("UserName") <> "HThompson") And _
        (Environ("UserName") <> "hthompson") Then

         MsgBox "File will be closed without saving - you do not have permission to save it."
     Else ' User is Rob, David or Helen.
         TempUserWantsToSaveFile = MsgBox("Would you like to save before closing?", _
                                          vbYesNoCancel)
         Select Case TempUserWantsToSaveFile
             Case vbYes
                 ' ThisWorkbook.Save will call Workbook_BeforeSave()
                 MsgBox ("Now calling ThisWorkbook.Save")
                 ThisWorkbook.Save

             Case vbNo
                 MsgBox ("DEBUG: file not saved")

             Case vbCancel
                 MsgBox ("DEBUG: cancel file close")
                 Cancel = True

             Case Else
                 'This is an error case - response should be yes, no or cancel.
                 MsgBox ("DEBUG: error: response should be yes, no or cancel.")
         End Select
     End If

 End If
 'else: workbook hasn't changed so just close the file
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
' Only save this worksheet if the user is David, Rob or myself.
MsgBox ("DEBUG: Workbook_BeforeSave")
If (Environ("UserName") <> "dwilson") And _
  (Environ("UserName") <> "DWilson") And _
  (Environ("UserName") <> "RGrant") And _
  (Environ("UserName") <> "rgrant") And _
  (Environ("UserName") <> "HThompson") And _
  (Environ("UserName") <> "hthompson") Then

  MsgBox "Sorry, only David and Rob can save this workbook!"
  Cancel = True
Else
' Hide all sheets except Dummy Sheet before saving.
' This will mean that if the workbook is opened with macros disabled,
' the user will not be able to see other people's sheets.

' Switch to the Dummy Sheet before continuing as you cannot
' update the visible flag for the active worksheet:
Worksheets("Dummy Sheet").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Dummy Sheet").Activate

   For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   ' Note the use of ThisWorkbook.Worksheets rather
   ' than ThisWorkbook.Sheets. This is because .Sheets
   ' contains both worksheets AND charts but "sht" is of
   ' type Worksheet so cannot be a chart (code falls over
   ' at any Chart sheet if .Sheets is used).
      If sht.Name <> "Dummy Sheet" Then

         sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Debug.Print sht.Name

         If sht.Name = "hthompson" Then MsgBox ("Hiding user sheet")

      End If
   Next
Cancel = False
MsgBox "DEBUG: Saving ..."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I see no `Activate` in your code ?

Comment: Hi Helen, you're describing some problem conditions based on code scenarios which don't seem to exist in the code you've provided. There is no `Activate` statement anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: Oops! Sorry David, typing error, the "Select" command in Workbook_BeforeSave() should have read "Activate"! Thanks, Helen.

Answer (score 0):

**Guess 1** - you have `Cancel = False` in your code and you are not aware of it.

**Guess 2** - try the following on empty Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Save
    Cancel = True

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print "Before Save"

End Sub
```

If you do not print "Before Save" in the console, then you should take a look at the events. E.g. `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

**Hint 1**:
Change your code like this to avoid reduplication:

```
ucase(Environ("UserName")) <> ucase("dwilson")
```

Thus with 3 lines with `ucase` you cover 6 in your code.

Comment: Hi Vityata, I've put debug into my code and it goes through Workbook_BeforeSave() but for some reason does not seem to action the "activate" command ... when it is run as part of the file closing event. It works fine with a simple ctrl-S save. Any ideas why? thanks, Helen.

Comment: @HelenT - have you tried `Application.EnableEvents = True`?

Comment: Hi Vityata, Just tried setting Application.EnableEvents = True when doc is opened, but still doesn't work :-( Thanks, Helen.